# How does Ingite affinity-collocation work?

Tags: ignite

I am reading through the https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation, but I didn't get a good unserstanding how 
the affinity-collocation works or its behavior.

Presume I have an Employee object(its id is 1000) whose companyId is 1, then this Employee object will be collocated with the Company object whose id is 1.
That is, they will reside in the same node but in different cache:

```
Employee Cache: <1000, EmployeeObjWhoseCompanyIdIs1>
Company Cache: <1, CompanyObj>
```

But What if there is a third cache, say Country Cache, and it also has a key that is 1, that is:

```
Country Cache: <1, CountryObj>
```

Then, will the Employee object and the Country object will also reside in the same node?

From the Affinity class definition,it only defines the 
`affKey` to which to collocate with, but it doesn't specify the cache that owns this `affKey`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will be stored on one node. However, I would treat this as a coincidence because it happens only because you used same types and values for keys in this particular case. Logically company ID and country ID are not related to each other, so it's not correct to say that they are collocated.

Comment: Thanks @Valentin for the helpful answer. But I don't think this is a coincidence,:-). In real cases, there many database tables that are using auto increment feature for the id field. That is, they are both number type(or Long type) and they will be the same in value. I think this will dramatically increase the change that some logically incorrect thing happens( company ID and country ID  are not related,but they will stay on the same node)

Comment: @Tom, I meant that semantically this is a coincidence. I.e. business logic should never rely on this fact and treat it as a collocation, because it is not. However, this will happen pretty often indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation,and now I understood the behavior and its effect.